# Ajax Call to Load Current Time

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I need to call code from an ajax request this call is for the current time. I do not know how to do this I set up an html file with the working clock in it. The page I am calling to does not present the clock it loads the text from $container1 but not the clock and date? Does Anyone know why? If the text from container 1 is loading fine why Is the current time and date clock not working?

Heres what I have so far in the html that the data is being grabbed from.

```
var mydate=new Date()
var year=mydate.getYear()
if (year < 1000)
year+=1900
var day=mydate.getDay()
var month=mydate.getMonth()
var daym=mydate.getDate()
if (daym<10)
daym="0"+daym
var dayarray=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")
var montharray=new Array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")
var date=new Date();
var hours=date.getHours();
var minutes=date.getMinutes();
 var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
var s=date.getSeconds();
s = s < 10 ? '0'+s : s;
var Time = "Current Time:&nbsp;  ";
var Text = "Last Updated:  ";

      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =Time+" "+dayarray[day]+" "+montharray[month]+"/"+daym+"/"+year+" "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+s+" "+ampm; 
document.getElementById('time2').innerHTML =Text+" "+dayarray[day]; 
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container1">
<div id="left">By TrueLogic Company
    <p>Edited By International Electronic Components</p>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div id="time2"></div>[LastBuuild]
    <p>
        <div id="time"></div>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the page I want it loaded to ive tried several hings but this is what I have now.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function refreshPage () {
     var page_y = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop; 
     window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?page_y=' + page_y;

}
     window.onload = function () {
         setTimeout(refreshPage, 3000);
            if (window.location.href.indexOf('page_y') != -1 ) {
                var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split("&")[0].split("=");
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = match[1];

    }

{
     $('#container').load('C:/Program%20Files/TrueChem/Data/dashboard/src/Test.HTML #container1');
  }
}
</script>

<div id="container">
```

Comment: Can you please remove all irrelevant code? Nobody wants to read all this.

Comment: show us only that code, where you r getting problem.

Comment: Tried clearing out unnecessary code but i'm not quite sure what that is or isn't.

Comment: So everyone thanks for hitting the down button on my question that really helps me out you are all great, im just trying to learn here and that makes it much more pleasant to loose reputation points for asking a question the wrong way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a *lot* of unnecessary code here, but if I were to guess I'd say the problem is this:

```
$('#container').load('C:/Program%20Files/TrueChem/Data/dashboard/src/Test.HTML #container1');
```

You're trying to load a file from the local file system via JavaScript.  That's not going to work for *obvious* security reasons.  (Imagine if any website could access your local files.)

When you use browser debugging tools, does this even attempt to make an AJAX request?  Does it throw an error?  (I'm guessing/hoping the latter.)

Your AJAX request needs to be to an HTTP host (a web server, basically) which would respond with the data in question.  JavaScript can't load local files.

**Edit:** Based on the comment thread below, it sounds like the heart of the problem is that you're trying to run some JavaScript code on one page by loading it via AJAX from another page.  This probably won't work.  The page doesn't actually *have* the value you're looking for, it has the code which generates the value.  And that code probably isn't being executed when you fetch it via AJAX.

However, since it's the code you're after and not the content of the page, you shouldn't even really be loading the page via AJAX.  You should just put the code in a separate file and reference that file on both pages.

Just move the JavaScript code into a .js file and reference that file on both pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dateTimeCalculations.js"></script>
```

That will give you access to the code which generates the value, and you can populate that value into elements on the page.

Comment: That won't work I can't use a http because these aren't websites they are browser representations of a piece of software. Its a dashboard. The code works it pulls the data it just doesn't pull all of it the time isn't working but the rest is?

Comment: and i'm writing this in notepad so I don't have browser debugging tools as far as I know.

Comment: @chrisw.iec: `"I can't use a http because these aren't websites"` - If this is supposed to be a local application then it should be written as one. You're using HTML/JavaScript, which is designed for in-browser web applications. `"the time isn't working but the rest is"` - Can you be more specific? In what way does it fail? Does the AJAX request to that file actually succeed? There's a lot of extra code here unrelated to the problem, so you need to help us narrow it down. `"I don't have browser debugging tools"` - If you aren't viewing this webpage in a browser, what are you viewing it in?

Comment: The Ajax request works as in it grabs the data and posts it except for loading the Time. The By trueLogic and and Edited by INternational Electronic Components posts, while the time does not.

Comment: I tried clearing out unnecessary code, but don't exactly know what that is or isn't.

Comment: its being viewed in a browser, sorry. I don't know what browser debugging is I guess?

Comment: @chrisw.iec: Define "the time does not load." What does that actually mean in the code? The HTML in the first code sample doesn't have any content in its `#time` element. The second code sample shows a lot of logic for calculating some date/time value(s), but doesn't do anything with them. You have to be specific about how this isn't working. We can't debug it for you, especially if you won't tell us what it's even supposed to do. "It's supposed to load the time" doesn't mean anything to anybody except you, you have to indicate where in the code it's failing.

Comment: @chrisw.iec: Browser debugging tools would be in-browser tools for helping you develop in-browser applications.  Firebug or Chrome tools, for example, depending on which browser you use.

Comment: Let me better explain this is connected to a piece of software that you plug mathematical equations into for chemical titration analysis. you do the analysis plug the numbers in and it spits out the concentrations of components say in a gold plating bath it stores these and gives you statistical data. The browser is a visual representation of this. it tells you the last test value, the time till the next schedule is due statistical values such as CpK so on and so forth. There are a lot of images and i'm testing out using ajax to refresh instead of normal refresh.

Comment: I reposted whats in the HTML file I'm trying to pull from. I need the time and text from that page to be posted onto the page that is pulling it...The second code I posted is the page that is pulling the data.

Comment: So there is no way to load a div that has a counting clock in it from an different html file?

Comment: I think I've reworded my question to better suite the sites rules can you please review?

Comment: @chrisw.iec: So the first code sample is what's being loaded in the AJAX request by the second code sample?  Keep in mind the first sample doesn't actually *contain* the value you're looking for.  It contains JavaScript code to *calculate* the value.  I'll bet that code isn't being executed when it's loaded dynamically by the second code sample.  Can you confirm that it is by debugging?  If not, that's probably the problem.  If all you need to load is the code to calculate a value, you should put that code into its own file and have both pages reference that file as code.

Comment: the debugging tools in IE10 do not throw an error when I debug. So you're saying I should load the var time into a file and call that, i'm not sure I understand your explanation?

Comment: @chrisw.iec: Well, it looks like you're trying to re-use the JavaScript that's on one page on another page.  So instead of trying to load the page itself via AJAX, just move the JavaScript code into a `.js` file.  Then add that file as a `script` tag in each of the HTML files.  No need for AJAX, each of the files can just run the JavaScript directly.

Comment: good enough answer for me can you post  that as an answer and i'll accept it?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble so I turned the page with the javascript that sets up the time into a js file. Now how do I access the js file I want the current time in. Please be specific  step by step if possible, i'm pretty slow learning disability type.

Comment: I just need to know what to put in the js file and what format and what to put in the file i'm calling from?

Comment: @chrisw.iec: You should really start with some introductory tutorials to HTML and JavaScript, honestly.  At its simplest, the `.js` file would contain only JavaScript code.  Then the `.html` files would reference it in a `script` tag as demonstrated in the edit to my answer.  That reference then *acts like* the JavaScript code is right there in the `.html` file, it's just actually in a separate file.  This way you only have to write the JavaScript code once, but it can be used by multiple HTML pages.

Comment: so then I just put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="dateTimeCalculations.js"></script>` in the html body where I want it to show up?

Comment: @chrisw.iec: If that's the name of the `.js` file you create, then you would include that tag where you want the script to be referenced.  The HTML file will likely still need a line or two of JavaScript in order to use that code, depending on how you design it.

Comment: Thanks i'll work on it